# Tensorflow - How to check what weights were loaded

Tags: tensorflow

I have a tensorflow pre-trained model that I loaded at test time. My question is, how can I verify that all the weights in my architecture have been updated ?

1. Will tensorflow raise an error if I have additional weights in my code ?
2. Will tensorflow raise an error if I have less weights in my code ?

Below is a simple snippet

```
n_classes = 2
batch_size=1000

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10, embedding_size], name='embedding') 
keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, name='keep_prob')

# weights - fc
fc1_w = tf.get_variable("fc1_w", shape=[1024, 256])
fc2_w = tf.get_variable("fc2_w", shape=[256, 256])
clf_w = tf.get_variable("clf_w", shape=[256, 2])

fc1_b = tf.get_variable("fc1_b", shape=[256])
fc2_b = tf.get_variable("fc2_b", shape=[256])
clf_b = tf.get_variable("clf_b", shape=[2])

# weights - lstm 
lstm  = tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(num_units = 1024, state_is_tuple=True)
lstm_state = lstm.zero_state(batch_size, tf.float32)

sess = tf.Session()
saver = tf.train.Saver()
saver.restore(sess, "./checkpoints/model-24000")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will tensorflow raise an error if I have additional weights in my code
>   ?

Yes.

> Will tensorflow raise an error if I have less weights in my code ?

No.

`tf.train.Saver()` will check all (saveable or trainable) variables in your code and assign them the value of the same name in the pre-trained model.

You can also specify the `var_list`, like `tf.train.Saver(var_list=a_list_of_variables)` to force it check parts of variables in the list.

Comment: thanks ! do you know how I can check for the lstm ? I passed [fc1_w, fc2_w, lstm, lstm_state] but got an error for the lstms

Comment: I'm not sure about the error you got and I don't know much about lstm. but I don't think lstm and lstm_state are variables. Maybe `lstm.variables()` is the list of variables in lstm and is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if there any discrepancies between the graph you are using and the weights you are loading, tensorflow will inform you of the missing/additional variables.